# .htacces /?p=test changed into /test

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**This is the URL**
http://www.example.com/main/index.php?p=test

**I want it to become this**
http://www.example.com/test

**My current .htaccess looks like this**

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^template\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^./]*)/?$ /index.php/?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**With these rules i only get this at the end**
/main/

I have tried many other Rewrite Rules but this rule seems to be the closest i can get.

**MY FIX**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /main/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

It does not do exactly what i wanted but i is a close as i can get and work.
Instead of seeing http://www.example.com/main/index.php?p=test we see http://www.example.com/main/test/
Was hoping for /test but /test/ will do. I also have to have this in each sub folder and change /main/ to the folder name, but that is automated so i am not that worried about it Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading slash. `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^template/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ /index.php/?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If your original URI is `/test` then it will **internally rewrite** that to `/index.php?p=test` (URL will not change in browser). Make sure this is your first rule and this is in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: I was using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to check before i change anything. Using your rules and this URL http://www.example.com/main/index.php?p=test

Comment: Oh you want reverse redirect only. I will edit the rule. And test it on your web server not on that site (its unreliable).

Comment: I put those rules in my htaccess it messed up alot of other pages not pulling correct files.

Comment: Please provide details like what exactly is the problem? Do you have only these rules or some other rules also?

Comment: You still didn't tell what problem are you facing with this? Is this the only .htaccess OR you have another? Also see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Place the .htaccess file in root (/) not main folder (/main)

UPDATE

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ main/index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

Please try the above

Comment: It is. The main folder is just a Sub Dir.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had updated my answer. I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have this in the root directory, therefore you need to add main to your htaccess regex otherwise the code will point to the wrong directory. Let me know if this works

```
# add /main
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+main/index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

#add /main
RewriteRule ^([^./]*)/?$ /main/index.php/?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: I tested this on one of my websites and it worked

Comment: My root directory for my website is / then i have a few "portals" under that /test/ and /main/ all these sites need to have the ?p=var replace with /var i used your rules and it kinda worked. I put in the htaccess at / with the index for my site. The ?p=var got changed to /var but it over rid my websites index with my /main/ index and then i had no /main/ index

Comment: does http://www.example.com/main/index.php?p=test change to http://www.example.com/test ?

Comment: http://example.com/main/index.php?p=test changed to http://example.com/main/test but http://example.com/index.php changed to http://example.com/main/index.php and http://example.com/main/index.php did not exist